# Need to throw checked exception in implementation, but it's not thrown by the interface?

Tags: java, exception, accumulo

I'm implementing the Accumulo [BatchWriter](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.5/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/BatchWriter.html) interface to perform some additional computation over records before inserting. That computation may throw a checked exception if something goes wrong, but the only exception thrown by BatchWriter is the [MutationsRejectedException](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.4/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/MutationsRejectedException.html). As such, I'm unable to throw the necessary checked exception when an error occurs in the pre-processing I'm trying to do.

Now, I could catch the checked exception and simply throw another exception in its place: either an unchecked exception like some RuntimeException or a MutationsRejectedException. Neither option seems great - an unchecked exception is a poor simulacrum of the exception I'd like to actually throw while throwing a MutationsRejectedException wouldn't allow me to see the actual cause of the error.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: Can't you just wrap your checked exception in a runtime exception and throw that?

Comment: @Mena doesn't that defeat the purpose of throwing a checked exception: "Can't you just wrap your warning in a surprise and throw that?"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with either a custom unchecked exception or the provided `MutationsRejectedException`. In either case you wrap the root cause.

Comment: @Andreas not if the forced inheritance doesn't allow you to do anything else, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "MutationsRejectedException wouldn't allow me to see the actual cause of the error."

Yes [MutationsRejectedException](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/MutationsRejectedException.html) would allow you to see the actual cause via [chained exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html).
Note the "Throwable cause" in the constructor.
Code for version 1.7;

```
try{
    //...
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new MutationsRejectedException(null, null, (Map<TabletId,Set<SecurityErrorCode>>)null, null, 1, e);
}
```

.

```
try{
    //...
} catch (MutationsRejectedException e) {
    Throwable c = e.getCause();
    if(c instanceof MyException){
        //...
    }else{
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. MutationsRejectedException doesn't have a constructor of that form though (String, Exception). Do you recommend something like: `catch (MyException e) {throw new MutationsRejectedException(null, null, null, null, 0, e);}` ?

Comment: Just saw your edits, thanks. The MRE constructor you use in the first code block is deprecated - is that a real problem and if so can you suggest a workaround? The constructor I suggested in my previous comment gets flagged as "ambigious" so that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @benjaminhkaiser, to fix the ambiguous error, you can cast the null values. like `throw new MutationsRejectedException(null, null, (Map<TabletId,Set<SecurityErrorCode>>) null, null, 1, e);`

Comment: @benjaminhkaiser edited to reflect the newer API (I wrongly assumed you were using the one you linked to)

Answer (score 3):

The `BatchWriter` interface actually covers exactly your situation by expecting you to wrap whatever root cause you got into its `MutationsRejectedException`. That is much better design than declaring a general `Exception` and exception translation has been the recommended Java idiom since version 1.3 or so.

With `throws Exception` hopefully crossed out as an antipattern, all the choice you have is between exception translation and the "sneaky throw" idiom. I believe your preference would be the former, especially considering that the latter is very similar to having `throws Exception`, but more obscure.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the syntax for wrapping my exception in a MutationsRejectedException? Both forms I have attempted cause warnings: `throw new MutationsRejectedException(null, null, null, 1, e);` is deprecated and `throw new MutationsRejectedException(null, null, null, null, 1, e);` is ambiguous.

Comment: Cast the 3rd argument to `Map<TabletId,Set<SecurityErrorCode>>`. But I must wonder why you have nothing better to pass than all nulls, it seems like abuse of API. The framework expects those parameters for a reason.